# Passing entities to other layers? (ddd noob)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, domain-driven-design, sharp-architecture

I am exploring sharp architecture, and have seen that it is actually passing the entities around to other layer (as far as presentation layers). Shouldn't it be exposing interfaces of the entities to make it more loosely coupled? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can pratice DDD in many ways and most important is to actually look at your project needs and situation. If you will pratice DDD on a asp.net MVP or MVC web application and the the application will probably not talking to other external systems. Then it can be overkill to use a service layer and DTO objects just for NOT letting the presentation layer know anything about the domain. Most important is that you hide/remove knowledge of creation of entities, domain logic and possibilites to put entities in a invalid state. All this can be achieved with a good Domain entity api. Then I feel it can be a good practice to send entities down to presention layer. You can also use repositories for loading entities in your Controller/Presenter classes in presentation layer.
If you look at a lot of DDD examples you'll find that people tend to to what suites them best. 
I have never seen any example and practices where you expose your entities with interfaces. You can achieve a lot with just internal, protected and readonly attributes. This will hide api features for presentation layer.

/Best regards BacceSR